# Mapping key press event qt

Tags: c++, qt

How to detect which key was pressed by an user?
Tried to search web but couldn't find really anything interesting.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at [keyPressEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to detect keypresses globally (useful for application shortcuts etc), you'll need to make one of your `QObject`s the eventFilter for the application, by first overloading `QObject::eventFilter`:

```
bool cKeyPressEater::eventFilter(QObject *Object, QEvent *Event)
{
  if (Event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
  {
    QKeyEvent *KeyEvent = (QKeyEvent*)Event;

    switch(KeyEvent->key())
    {
      case Qt::Key_F1:
        //do something
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

...and then installing that object as the `eventFilter` for your application:

```
QObject *KeyPressEater = GetYourEventFilterObject();
QCoreApplication::instance()->installEventFilter(KeyPressEater);
```

Otherwise, as @Mat says above, just overload [`QWidget::keyPressEvent`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent). You'll need to [`setFocusPolicy`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop) and actually have focus in order to get the key presses.